# WPF vs XNA for a slots game development ??? What to use?

Tags: wpf, xna

I want to develop Video slots Game (Vegas style casino slots) where 
   - Various skins can be changed easily to give slots game a different look/feel to user
   - Game is playable on computer with Win 7 (Xbox/Zune/Linux is not the target platform)
   - client/server application where new skin on all clients can be installed from server
   - ME an my buddy will be the only team for this development

I am new to WPF, XNA and silverlight.

Which technology you think will be the best to achieve this ?

Many Thanks..!!!

Answer (score 0):

With XNA it would be easier to develop Games. It gives you to design 3d space easily. If you want to have flexibility of code with WPF, you can also host the XNA game inside your WPF application :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XnaInWPF.aspx

:)

Answer (score 0):

Using XNA would potentially make it more portable (to the "non targets" mentioned), allow access to more advanced graphic manipulation within the "library bundle", and is specifically designed to support game development (with tools tailored around this goal). I would imagine that the skinning methods, while different, are equally as attainable in both environments.